# Paypal Recurring Payment issue

Tags: paypal-subscriptions

My application allows subscription services and i am using paypal's recurring payment for this. There according to there manual, the order i used is 
SetExperssCheckOut-->GetExppressCheckOut-->DoExpressCheckOut->CreateRecurringPayment Profile.

On DoExpressCheckOut event iteself my first payment is made and after that on creating the recurring payment profile the next payment is made, ie if I have a daily subscription , on the end of 3rd day, no of payments made =4 (3 from the recurring payment and 1 from the get express checkout). I want only 3 payments at the end of 3rdday. The code I used is:

```
    GetExpressCheckout getExpressCheckout = new GetExpressCheckout();
        GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseType getExpressCheckoutResponse = getExpressCheckout.ECGetExpressCheckoutCode(token);

        if (getExpressCheckoutResponse.Ack == AckCodeType.Success)
        {
            ExpressCheckout expressCheckout = new ExpressCheckout();
            DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType doExpressCheckoutResponse = expressCheckout.DoExpressCheckoutPayment
                                                        (
                                                            token,
                                                            getExpressCheckoutResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails.PayerInfo.PayerID,
                                                            PayPalSettings.OrderAmount,
                                                            PaymentActionCodeType.Sale,
                                                            CurrencyCodeType.USD
                                                        );

            if (doExpressCheckoutResponse.Ack == AckCodeType.Success)
            {
                //create Recurring Payment Profile
                CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile createRecurringPaymentsProfile = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile();
                CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType recurringPaymentProfileResponse = createRecurringPaymentsProfile.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileCode(
                                                                                                doExpressCheckoutResponse.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseDetails.Token,
                                                                                                doExpressCheckoutResponse.Timestamp,
                                                                                                PayPalSettings.OrderAmount,
                                                                                                1,
                                                                                                BillingPeriodType.Day,//BillingPeriodType.Month
                                                                                                CurrencyCodeType.USD
                                                                                                );
                if (recurringPaymentProfileResponse.Ack == AckCodeType.Success)
                {
//Do something
}
```

How can I make all payments under the recurring payment section ?

Answer (score 1):

When using Recurring Payments the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call isn't required. When the customer is redirected to PayPal for authentication they submit their agreement to the scheduled payments.

Try skipping the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call and this should take care of the extra payment.

Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: If i skip DoExpressCheckoutPayment  call, where do i create my recurring payment profile and also can I make any initial payment for the transaction?

Comment: The creation can occur after the GetExpressCheckoutDetails is executed as the customer has agreed to the profile when visiting PayPal so there is no need for the DoExpressCheckoutPayment call.

Based on the information you've provided the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API call already has a start date of the same day it's created or it has an initial payment. If it does not, you can charge an initial payment by adding "INITAMT" with the amount you'd like to charge during creation. Let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: I have given Iniitial amount and skipped the DoExpressCheckoutPayment section. After that on pay my profile status remains as pending. When will that change to active and also i dint get any trasaction id in returns from the recurring payment response object